# Swift SequenceType not working

Tags: swift, foreach, generator, sequence, for-in-loop

I'm trying to implement a SequenceType / GeneratorType example and getting an error that doesn't quite make sense.

Here's the code:

```
// Here's my GeneratorType - it creates a random-number Generator:
struct RandomNumberGenerator:GeneratorType {
    typealias Element = Int
    mutating func next() -> Element? {
       return Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    }
}
```

When I call this (in Playgrounds) it works perfectly well:

```
var randyNum = RandomNumberGenerator()
randyNum.next()   // this shows a valid random number in the Gutter
// And calling it from within a println also works:
println("randyNum = \(randyNum.next()!)")
```

So far so so good.

Next is the SequenceType:

```
struct RandomNumbersSequence:SequenceType {
    typealias Generator = RandomNumberGenerator
    var numberOfRandomNumbers:Int

    init(maxNum:Int) {
        numberOfRandomNumbers = maxNum
    }

    func generate() -> Generator {
        for i in 1...numberOfRandomNumbers {
          var randNum = Generator()
          randNum.next()
          return randNum
       }
    } 

}
```

That's what's generating an error: `'Type RandomNumberSequence' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'`. (Xcode is showing this error right on that first line of the declaration `struct RandomNumbersSequence:SequenceType` statement.)

I actually think the *logic* of my `for` loop may be wrong - meaning I won't get the results I actually want - but regardless, in terms of satisfying what the `SequenceType` Protocol is requiring, I think I got that much right. 
So what's causing this error?

Comment: Just to check – you are trying to write a sequence that serves up x number of random numbers?  I.e. if you create `let seq = RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 5)`, then do `for i in seq { }` you’ll get 5 random numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn’t quite how generators work.  Assuming you want to serve up a set number of random numbers, you have the right idea about taking a maximum as a parameter, but you need to store that in the generator, as well, plus some state for where it is up to.

The idea with a generator is that it stores its state, and every time you call `next()` you return the next element.  So if you want to generate a run of up to `n` numbers, you could do something like the following:

```
struct RandomNumberGenerator: GeneratorType {
    let n: Int
    var i = 0
    init(count: Int) { self.n = count }

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        if i++ < n {
            return Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you don’t need a `for` loop here.  Just each time `next()` is called, `i` is incremented, until it reaches the max, then the generator starts returning `nil`.

The purpose of `SequenceType` is to serve up fresh generators:

```
struct RandomNumberSequence: SequenceType {
    let n: Int
    init(count: Int) { self.n = count }

    func generate() -> RandomNumberGenerator {
        return RandomNumberGenerator(count: n)
    }
}
```

Given this, you can now use it to generate a sequence of a fixed number of random integers:

```
let seq = RandomNumberSequence(count: 3)

for x in seq {
     // loops 3 times with x being a new random number each time
}

// every time you use seq, you get a new set of 3 numbers
",".join(map(seq,toString))  // prints 3 comma-separated random nums

// but when you create a generator, it gets “used up”
var gen = seq.generate()
println(gen.next()) // prints a random number
println(gen.next()) // prints another random number
println(gen.next()) // prints the third
println(gen.next()) // prints nil
println(gen.next()) // and will keep printing nil

gen = seq.generate()
println(gen.next()) // will print the first of a new set of 3 numbers
```

Creating these stateful generators is quite a common problem, so the standard library has a helper struct, `GeneratorOf`, that allows to you skip defining them.  It takes a closure that each time it is called should return the next value to generate:

```
struct RandomNumbersSequence: SequenceType {
    let maxNum: Int

    init(maxNum: Int) { self.maxNum = maxNum }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int> {
        // counter to track how many have been generated
        var n = 0
        return GeneratorOf {
            // the closure “captures” n
            if n++ < self.maxNum {
                return Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nhgrif ok, I was just gonna ask you about that. But will do. You both deserve credit. @Airspeed - thanks for the explanation - its very thorough and I totally get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing:

> 'Type RandomNumberSequence' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Always means that your class or struct is missing something that the protocol declares as required.

In this case, we're missing the `generate() -> Generator` method.  "But, it's right there!" you say?  Well, it is, but it's not compiling.

> ```
> func generate() -> Generator {
>     for i in 1...numberOfRandomNumbers {
>         var randNum = Generator()
>         randNum.next()
>         return randNum
>     }
> }
> ```

The problem is, what if you initialize your struct with `numberOfRandomNumbers` less than or equal to `0`?  Your loop executes zero times and `generate` can't return anything.

I'm not sure *exactly* what logic you're trying to to do in this loop, but we can fix the compilation errors by simply a adding a return statement that will return a `Generator`:

```
func generate() -> Generator {
    for i in 1...numberOfRandomNumbers {
        var randNum = Generator()
        randNum.next()
        return randNum
    }
    return Generator()
}
```

This won't do what you're trying to accomplish.  This isn't how generators are supposed to work.  But it will fix the `generate() -> Generator` method and allow your struct to now conform to the protocol.

Comment: Hmm, that looked really good - but its still not working. I made the change you suggested, but now I'm getting this: `Swift._Sequence_Type... note: protocol requires nested type 'Generator'  typealias Generator : GeneratorType`  . Also this: `note: possibly intended match 'Generator' does not conform to 'GeneratorType'    typealias Generator = RandomNumberGenerator`.  Very strange...

Comment: Yeah I think its a Playgrounds thing. It seems to be ok when run as an Xcode project...still checking...

Comment: Yeah, its def. Playgrounds - works in Xcode - HOWEVER... I'm getting an infinite loop - it keep generating random numbers forever. What I'm _trying_ to do here is simply create a sequence of X number of random numbers, where I can pass-in the value for X every time I create a sequence. But when I call it - like this: `var randySequence = RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 10)`, it just runs and runs and runs... I thought my `for` loop would limit it to whatever number I pass-in. Obviously I'm not quite getting something about this sequencing business. Any ideas?

Comment: Post a question about your broken `for` loop.  This question was about conforming to the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 3, you can choose one of the three `RandomNumbersSequence` implementations in order to solve your problem.

---

## 1. Using a struct that conforms to `Sequence` protocol and a struct that conforms to `IteratorProtocol` protocol

The following Playground code shows how to implement a `RandomNumbersSequence` struct that conforms to `Sequence` and that uses a `RandomNumbersIterator` struct that conforms to `IteratorProtocol` protocol:

```
import Darwin // required for arc4random_uniform

struct RandomNumbersIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    
    let maxNum: Int
    var n = 0

    init(maxNum: Int) {
        self.maxNum = maxNum
    }

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        n += 1
        return n <= self.maxNum ? Int(arc4random_uniform(10)) : nil
    }

}

struct RandomNumbersSequence: Sequence {
    
    let maxNum: Int
    
    init(maxNum: Int) {
        self.maxNum = maxNum
    }
    
    func makeIterator() -> RandomNumbersIterator {
        return RandomNumbersIterator(maxNum: maxNum)
    }
    
}
```

Usage #1:

```
for value in RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3) {
    print(value)
}

/*
 may print:
 5
 7
 3
 */
```

Usage #2:

```
let randomArray = Array(RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3))
print(randomArray)

/*
 may print: [7, 6, 1]
 */
```

Usage #3:

```
let randomSequence = RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3)
var randomGenerator = randomSequence.makeIterator()

randomGenerator.next() // may return: 4
randomGenerator.next() // may return: 8
randomGenerator.next() // may return: 3
randomGenerator.next() // will return: nil
```

---

## 2. Using a struct that conforms to `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol` protocols

The following Playground code shows how to implement a `RandomNumbersSequence` struct that conforms to `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol` protocols:

```
import Darwin // required for arc4random_uniform

struct RandomNumbersSequence: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    
    let maxNum: Int
    var n = 0
    
    init(maxNum: Int) {
        self.maxNum = maxNum
    }
    
    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        n += 1
        return n <= self.maxNum ? Int(arc4random_uniform(10)) : nil
    }
    
}
```

Usage #1:

```
for value in RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3) {
    print(value)
}

/*
 may print:
 5
 7
 3
 */
```

Usage #2:

```
let randomArray = Array(RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3))
print(randomArray)

/*
 may print: [7, 6, 1]
 */
```

Usage #3:

```
var randomSequence = RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3)

randomSequence.next() // may return: 4
randomSequence.next() // may return: 8
randomSequence.next() // may return: 3
randomSequence.next() // will return: nil
```

---

## 3. Using `AnyIterator` and a struct that conforms to `Sequence`

As an alternative to the previous implementation, you can use `AnyIterator<T>` as the return type of the `makeIterator` method inside your `Sequence` protocol conforming struct. The following Playground code shows how to implement it with your `RandomNumbersSequence` struct:

```
import Darwin // required for arc4random_uniform

struct RandomNumbersSequence: Sequence {
    
    let maxNum: Int
    
    init(maxNum: Int) {
        self.maxNum = maxNum
    }
    
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Int> {
        var n = 0
        let iterator: AnyIterator<Int> = AnyIterator {
            n += 1
            return n <= self.maxNum ? Int(arc4random_uniform(10)) : nil
        }
        return iterator
    }
    
}
```

Usage #1:

```
for value in RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3) {
    print(value)
}

/*
may print:
5
7
3
*/
```

Usage #2:

```
let randomArray = Array(RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3))
print(randomArray)

/*
may print: [7, 6, 1]
*/
```

Usage #3:

```
let randomSequence = RandomNumbersSequence(maxNum: 3)
let randomGenerator = randomSequence.makeIterator()

randomGenerator.next() // may return: 4
randomGenerator.next() // may return: 8
randomGenerator.next() // may return: 3
randomGenerator.next() // will return: nil
```